# Inline style without use of the head tag

Tags: html, css, email

I'm creating a HTML email for a client. Usually I whack the following bit of code in the head of the document which fixes some issues with rendering on iOS devices.

```
<style type="text/css">
HTML {
-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
}
body {
background-color: #c9c9c9;
}
.ExternalClass * {line-height: 100%;}
```

However this time client requires the email be marked up using DotMailer's Easy Editor tags - so they can drag and drop content etc. - and DotMailer refuses to acknowledge I've marked it up with it's proprietary tags unless I scrap all use of HTML, HEAD and BODY tags, leaving just the stuff between the BODY tags.

Any ideas of a work around? A style tag can't go in the body and I can't put the styles inline on the individual elements because they all get appended later.

Apologies if it's a niche question but I figured someone might be able to come up with a creative solution. DotMailer's staff have been useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dotmailer you have an option to view it in code view, when you are at the dragging and dropping stage. At the top of the code you can add `<style>` tags and they will work perfectly. I have built a few dotmailer templates and this is how you mark them up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion man. I just gave this a try but it didn't work. Something about the way DotMailer processes uploads, head tags and the styles within them get stripped off and then added back in later when emails are sent or something. Adding a head in the source doesn't seem to do anything!

Comment: Wait, I did away with the head tag and it worked perfectly! Cheers!

I'm so glad HTML has moved on from this type of rubbish...

Comment: Yeah I'm glad HTML has moved on too. Dotmailer may reject it at upload stage but once you have uploaded it, you can access it and edit the code. That's the time to start adding in `<style>` tags etc. Glad to help.